# No Internet Options at all Fresh Install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, ethernet

I have installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.04.1 on a new desktop PC. The install seemed to have gone well and everything is working, except Internet. I have absolutely no Internet options on the device at all. Clicking the drop down in the top right has options for volume, settings, lock, and power off. That’s it. Opening settings has “Network” as a tab but inside of that only has VPN and Network Proxy settings. I have the Desktop hardwired (cable works on laptop) but the mobo supports WiFi as well. I have done lots of googling on this but am unable to find a solution. Any help you all can provide would be amazing!

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about the system you installed Ubuntu on?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1301687/edit) your question and add more details and we might be able to point you in the right direction for installing the correct network drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation while doing a reinstall of 20.04.  I got around it by using an ethernet cable and making a wired connection.  The Ubuntu live DVD picked that right up.